# Flutter - show video length while recording video

Tags: flutter, camera, video-recording

I am using the camera package to record video in my app, via the
CameraController.startVideoRecording() method.

I would like to display the increasing value for the length of the video while recording.

My initial thought was to create a timer.  But, I wonder if there is a better solution that is more integrated with the video recording itself, such a a callback/event that I can listen to for the current length of the video or some property related to the video that I can interrogate?

Any suggestions/recommendations or examples are appreciated.

Thanks